# Add cell string to another cell if 2 cells are the same for 2 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro that will go through a spreadsheet, and based on the first and last name being the same for 2 rows, add the contents of an ethnicity column to the first row.

eg.

```
FirstN|LastN |Ethnicity                                       |ID      |

Sally |Smith |Caucasian                                       |55555   |
Sally |Smith |Native American                                 |        |
Sally |Smith |Black/African American                          |        |
```

(after the macro runs)

```
Sally |Smith |Caucasian/Native American/Black/African American|55555   |
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? I read several different methods for VBA but have gotten confused as to what way would work to create this macro.

EDIT
There may be more than 2 rows that need to be combined, and the lower row(s) need to be deleted or removed some how.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. This isn't a coding service, it is for questions relating to code.

Comment: This can be done with a single formula + filtering. Is vba absolutely required?

Comment: No, if it doesn't need to be VBA that's fine.

Comment: at most 2 rows, directly next to each other?

Comment: there can be more than 2 rows. Sometimes up to 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a formula, then you can do those:

Couple of assumptions I'm making:

- Sally is in cell `A2` (there are headers in row 1).
- No person has more than 2 ethnicities.

Now, for the steps:

1. Put a filter and sort by name and surname. This provides for any person having their names separated. (i.e. if there is a 'Sally Smith' at the top, there are no more 'Sally Smith' somewhere down in the sheet after different people).
2. In column D, put the formula `=if(and(A2=A3,B2=B3),C2&"/"&C3,"")`
3. Extend the filter to column D and filter out all the blanks.

That is does is it sees whether the names cells A2 and A3 are equal (names are the same), and whether the cells B2 and B3 are equal (surnames are the same).

If both are true, it's the same person, so we concatenate (using `&` is another way to concatenate besides using `concatenate()`) the two ethnicities.

Otherwise, if either the name, or username, or both are different, leave as blank.

To delete the redundant rows altogether, copy/paste values on column D, filter on the blank cells in column D and delete. Sort afterwards.

**EDIT: As per edit of question:**

The new steps:

1. Put a filter and sort by name and surname. (already explained above)
2. In column E, put the formula `=IF(AND(A1=A2,B1=B2),E1&"/"&C2,C2)` (I changed the formula to adapt to the new method)
3. In column F, put the formula `=if(and(A1=A2,B1=B2),F1+1,1)`
4. In column G, put the formula `=if(F3<F2,1,0)`
5. In column H, put the formula `=if(and(D2="",A1=A2,B1=B2),H1,D2)` (this takes the ID wherever it goes).

**Put the formulae as from row 2.** What step 3 does is putting an incremental number for the people with same name.

What step 4 does is checking for when the column F goes back to 1. This will identify your 'final rows to be kept'.

Here's my output from those formulae:
[image]

The green rows are what you keep (notice that there is `1` in column `G` that allows you to quickly spot them), and the columns A, B, C, E and H are the columns you keep in the final sheet. Don't forget to copy/paste values once you are done with the formulae and before deleting rows!

Comment: I did some quick research and it looks like the extra row will stick around if I use the formula method. I tried to delete duplicates but due to same name but different ID number it sees the duplicate entries as not duplicate (one cell has a number and the duplicate cell does not, thus being different)

Comment: @Bryan Does that mean that instead of the name, you would be using the ID? I'm not sure what you're saying here. Maybe it would be clearer if you edit your question with a table closer to that in your problem. If you want to remove the redundant rows now (I'm ignoring the ID for now with this), copy and paste values the formulas and filter on the blanks in column D only and delete them. Sort after that.

Comment: ah, I keep forgetting about the sort function to delete the rows without the ID

Comment: @Bryan Okay, to adapt the formula, I would use 2 helper columns (which can be removed later). Would you be fine with this?

Comment: @Bryan I amended my answer. This makes the procedure a bit longer, but it seems to do the trick. I try to prevent loss of information, like you can see in my post the id `22222` gets in the result even if it's not mentioned in the first row of 'Sammy Smith`.

Comment: Thanks that helps quite a bit.

Comment: If I knew of VBA, I'd propose something. Sorry about that ^^;

Comment: It looks like the F column formula is giving me "#VALUE!". this seems to be because of the formula referring to itself? (only when it comes to incrementing the value)

Comment: @Bryan Hmm are you putting the formulae as from row 2? I should have specified in my answer, oops!

Comment: I actually posted too quickly. I had a wrong cell referenced.

Answer (score 1):

If first `Sally` is in `A1` then `=IF(AND(A1=A2,B1=B2),C1&"/"&C2,"")`copied down as appropriate might suit. Assumes where not the same a blank ("") is preferred to repetition of the `C` value.